# Testing browsers simultaneously; receiving error

Tags: java, xml, maven, selenium, testng

Right now, I'm trying to work on my first test that will test browsers Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Safari in parallel.  But the following error that I'm getting is this:

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod beforeMethod
>   org.testng.TestNGException: 
>   Parameter 'browser' is required by @Configuration on method beforeMethod but >has not been marked @Optional or defined

I'm using Selenium, TestNG and Maven with the JAVA language. The XML test suite file and the java file are in the same folder in the directory. What I was able to find for the test suite XML file online is as follows (with class name values set to the correct package and class name):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="2" parallel="tests">
 <test name="ChromeTest">
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sqa.ts.multiBrowser.BrowserTest">
        </class>
    </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="FirefoxTest">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sqa.ts.multiBrowser.BrowserTest">
        </class>
    </classes>  
 </test>
 <test name="IETest">
    <parameter name="browser" value="ie" />
     <classes>
        <class name="com.sqa.ts.multiBrowser.BrowserTest">
        </class>
     </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="SafariTest">
    <parameter name="browser" value="safari" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sqa.ts.multiBrowser.BrowserTest">
        </class>
    </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Below is my code to just open the browser to make sure that it will run and pass:

```
package com.sqa.ts.multiBrowser;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class BrowserTest {

  private WebDriver driver;

  @Test
  public void testCaseOne() {
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.close();
  } 

  @BeforeMethod
  @Parameters("browser")
  public void beforeMethod(String browser) throws MalformedURLException {
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/Trevor/workspace/BrowserTest/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

    } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/Users/Trevor/workspace/BrowserTest/drivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

    } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("safari")) {
        driver = new SafariDriver();
    }
}

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {
    driver.quit();
  }

}
```

If anyone can give me an insight as to what is causing this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thank you.

Comment: Does putting @Parameters("browser") before @BeforeMethod fix your issue?

Comment: There seems absolutely no problem with above two files, as I copied these files as it is in my maven setup. It is invoking Chrome, IE, Firefox simultaneously.

Comment: How you are running the tests? You will receive above error only when you `Run as TestNG Test`. Try running it as `TestNG Suite` or `Maven Test`.

Comment: Thank you @mk08, running the TestNG Suite got the the testing to start working. :)

Comment: @Tscott: Great! Check below Sighil's answer too. You will eventually need it if you want to make it run everything via Maven!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the testNG configuration in the pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Following plugin executes the testng tests -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/com/sqa/ts/multiBrowser/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
</build>
```

Running **mvn clean install** or **mvn clean install** should run the test cases. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I will give this a try.  I didn't know you could do something like this in the pom.xml file.  I thought you could really update the dependencies or libraries.

Comment: Maven is a build tool with a lot of plugins... It is not for just dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like executing the XML file as Run as > Testng Suite.  That was the fix to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It worked with option = Run as > Testng Suite